# How can I solve "Your connection is not private"?

Tags: php, gitlab, laravel-5.3, digital-ocean, laravel-forge

When I access my production server on the chrome broswer, there exist error like this:

> This server could not prove that it is backend.secret.co.id; its security certificate expired 2 days ago. This may be caused by a misconfiguration or an attacker intercepting your connection. Your computer's clock is currently set to Thursday, February 8, 2018. Does that look right? If not, you should correct your system's clock and then refresh this page.

My full error like this:

[image]

My server is using forge laravel, DigitalOcean and GitLab

What have I to do to resolve this error?

Comment: _“its security certificate expired 2 days ago”_ - so, you need to go and get a new certificate ... check your hoster’s documenation/ FAQ on how to go about that.

Comment: @CBroe, Do you mean this one? https://imgur.com/a/2lggg. I using forge laravel. So I input the textfield and click "create signing request button"?

Comment: Since it says there that that’s the first step to creating a new certificate ...

Comment: @CBroe, Seems it's not free. So it must select Let's Encrypt(free)

Answer (score 2):

Your SSL/TLS certificate expired 3 days ago. You either need to replace the expired certificate with a new/renewed one, alternatively you can use services like [Let's Encrypt](https://letsencrypt.org/) (Disclaimer: I'm not affiliated with Let's Encrypt) for free SSL/TLS certificates. If you don't want to do either of this, you may want to disable SSL, but I wouldn't recommend it.

Comment: Do you mean this one? https://imgur.com/a/2lggg. I using forge laravel. So I input the textfield and click "create signing request button"?

Comment: @SuccessMan That will give you a CSR (Certificate Signing Request). You can carry that over to a SSL certificate seller to buy a new certificate. But I also see that you have a Let's Encrypt option there, I'd try that out first because it's free (paid certificates are starting at about $100 USD) and no need to type in this data (at least from my experience with the certbot on the command line).

Comment: Do you mean Let's Encrypt this one (https://postimg.org/image/kttx01351/) ? Of course I will choose the free option. I want to ask the process. Does the process like this? I delete the current certificate and after that I click obtain certificate button. I apologize if I ask in great detail. I am only afraid if I make mistakes, it will impact everywhere

Comment: @SuccessMan Yes you are correct. The full process is also described in [this Laracast](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/forge/setting-up-lets-encrypt-on-forge).

Comment: I had try it. I find the new problem. Look at this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48700055/how-can-i-solve-we-were-unable-to-obtain-a-letsencrypt-ssl-certificate-on-your