# How can I solve "We were unable to obtain a LetsEncrypt SSL certificate on your server" on the forge laravel?

Tags: php, ssl, certificate, forge, laravel-forge

My server using forge laravel(https://forge.laravel.com)

When I click obtain certificate button to add new certicate like this :

[image]

It does not work. There exist error like this :

```
We were unable to obtain a LetsEncrypt SSL certificate on your server
```

The full error like this :

[image]
[image]

How can I solve this error?

Comment: Looks like your Server responsed with the HTTP status code 403, which means the [Access to the server was denied](//httpstat.us/403). Have you set any access restrictions like .htaccess files or redirects that an automated system like that could not handle? If yes, you should disable them and retry it.

Comment: Also take a look at this: https://community.letsencrypt.org/t/type-unauthorized-detail-invalid-response-from/36183

Comment: @chade_, I am a bit confused. Because before that I did not set the server. But I will try to solve this problem. How do I disable them and retry it? Please answer this question with a detail answer. I using gitlab, forge laravel and digital ocean. Where I can set it up?

Comment: A .htaccess file can usally be found in the directory from where your files are hosted. You can disable by renaming them to e.g. `text.txt`. Also, it looks like you've set multiple domains for obtaining the certificate. I would try first with only one domain (e.g. you have example.com and example.net, try it first with example.com only), and if that don't work you may try and install the cerbot utility directly at the server (assuming that you have command line/SSH access)

Comment: @chade_ Okay. I do not have ssh access yet. But I will ask to my boss. Does access SSH via digital ocean? here https://postimg.org/image/jlo8bklod/. Click console link?

Comment: Yes that should work. For further discussion, let us continue in [chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/164808/discussion-between-success-man-and-chade).

Comment: @chade_ Are you online? I already have access to ssh server

Comment: Kinda. I'm currently in vacation, but I'll look by from time to time, to see I can help you further

Comment: @chade_ Okay. No problem